# Invoking counter in batch

Tags: batch-file

I m just trying to invoke a simple counter.To implement that I wrote the below script but the script is only giving me output as "Checking".

```
@echo off
echo checking
goto :check
:check
for /L %%a IN (1,1,4) do (
  echo %%a
  if %%a == 4 (
    echo a is 4 now
    echo congo
    goto:eof
  ) else (
    goto :check
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

a few Problems here:

1) you are missing a closing parantheses (very good visible when Code is properly intended)

2) any `goto` breaks your block (a block is everything between `(`and `)`

3) jumping ahead of your `for` Loop will start it again, resulting in a endless Loop

4) no Need to `goto :eof`, as `for` will end of it's own when the Counter reaches 4

5) no need to `goto <a label at the very next line>`

This results in the following Code:

```
@echo off
echo checking
for /L %%a IN (1,1,4) do (
  echo %%a
  if %%a == 4 (
    echo a is 4 now 
    echo congo 
  )
)
```